# My view are only loading after the repeat while, when query data using Parse

Tags: ios, swift

**Code**

```
class Trackbooking: UIViewController {
 var bookid=String()
@IBOutlet weak var loadingBar: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("track\(bookid)")

    loadingBar.startAnimating()




    let query=PFQuery(className: "bookings")

    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:bookid)
    do {
        var results=try query.getFirstObject()["Booked"] as! Int
       print(results)

        repeat{
              sleep(2)
            results=try query.getFirstObject()["Booked"] as! Int
            print("wait for it")

        }while results==0





    } catch {
        print("Unexpected non-vending-machine-related error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

}

According to my knowledge view did load is executed after the view set, but when I run this code my views were only displaying after the repeat while statement  why is that So,

Comment: to be more precise viewDidLoad is called when you create an object for that viewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to my knowledge view did load is executed after the view set

Exactly! And `viewDidLoad` is working perfectly. However, "the view is set" simply means `self.view` becomes not nil. It does not mean that you can *see* the view. Having the view in memory does not imply the view is displayed. I can have a view in memory like this:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

Can the view be seen after the above line of code is run? No.

You should write the code inside `viewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let query=PFQuery(className: "bookings")

    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:bookid)
    do {
        var results=try query.getFirstObject()["Booked"] as! Int
       print(results)

        repeat{
              sleep(2)
            results=try query.getFirstObject()["Booked"] as! Int
            print("wait for it")

        }while results==0





    } catch {
        print("Unexpected non-vending-machine-related error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Using `sleep(2)` might not be a good idea because it will freeze the app and it can't respond to user interactions during this time, which creates a bad user experience. I suggest you use a `Timer` scheduled at a fix rate of 2 seconds:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    do {
        var results=try query.getFirstObject()["Booked"] as! Int
        print("wait for it")
        if results != 0 {
            timer.invalidate() // stops the timer
        }
    } catch {
        print("Unexpected non-vending-machine-related error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: great Explanation!!

Comment: and how to understand these kind of lifecycles ,is there any documentation?

Comment: @newjourney You can read the docs for [`viewDidLoad`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload) and [`viewDidAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear). [This](https://www.appcoda.com/view-controller-lifecycle/) might also help.

Comment: and if i run  loadingBar.startAnimating() in view did appear its not animating ,Why sir?

Comment: @newjourney are you still using `sleep`? That might be the reason

Comment: @newjourney the screen needs time to respond to the message “please start animating this view”. But you are not giving it that time by calling `sleep`. `sleep` means pause for this amount of time.